# Elementos diferentes en dos listas

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy empezando en **Python** y tengo un ejercicio que no he podido resolver, espero me puedan ayudar.

Tengo dos listas:

```
a = [12,3,5,12,8,9,25,12,1,3,4,5,17,15]
b = [3,5,7,8,45,8,9,16,1,11,30,41,2,3,15,1,29,22]
```

Ahora quiero separar en una tercer lista `(c)` los elementos que no se encuentran en ambas listas pero no he podido conseguir que lo haga.

Alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?

Saludos y muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a *Stack Overflow en Español* Juan Carlos, cuál es el error que te arroja?

Answer (score 0):

Usando comprensión de listas, es bastante sencillo si lo vamos pensando por partes. Para saber que elementos de `a` no están contenidos en `b`:

```
list(e for e in a if e not in b)

[12, 12, 25, 12, 4, 17]
```

Luego hacemos lo mismo pero al revés, los elementos de `b` no contenidos en `a`

```
list(e for e in b if e not in a)

[7, 45, 16, 11, 30, 41, 2, 29, 22]
```

Por último sumamos las dos listas:

```
list(e for e in a if e not in b) + list(e for e in b if e not in a)

[12, 12, 25, 12, 4, 17, 7, 45, 16, 11, 30, 41, 2, 29, 22]
```

**Importante**: esto respetará cada elemento repetido, por ejemplo el valor `12` aparecerá 3 veces ya que son las veces que aparece en `a` (y no en `b`) . Sin embargo, si buscaras solo conocer los valores únicos no coincidentes en ambas listas, puedes usar una diferencia simétrica de esta forma:

```
list(set(a) ^ set(b))

[2, 4, 7, 11, 12, 16, 17, 22, 25, 29, 30, 41, 45]
```